# Перелистывание Viewpager с помощью Button

Tags: java, android, button, slider, android-viewpager

Прошу объяснить как *правильно* реализовать перелистывание Viewpager с помощью кнопок("предыдущий","следующий"), а не пальцев. Спасибо большое!

Comment: setCurrentItem()

Answer (score 3):

В обработчике нажатия кнопок написать:

```
// для кнопки "Следующий"
int current = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
int totalItems = mViewPage.getAdapter().getCount();
if(current < totalItems - 1) {
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);
}



// для кнопки "Предыдущий"
int current = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
if(current != 0) {
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(current - 1, true);
}
```

Когда находимся на первой странице (current == 0) имеет смысл убрать кнопку "Предыдущий", когда на последней (current == totalItems - 1) - убрать кнопку "Следующий".

Comment: Пробовал через обработчик кнопок, но выдает ошибку, выкидывает из приложения